# Working on three tables, my grouping by it's not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to list the difference between the number of tickets sold at the different
stations of one line between time1 and time2. I have three table: time1, time 2 and place.

```
create table fares_jan18 (
    station varchar(100),
    ff int
);

create table fares_feb1 (
   station varchar(100),
   ff int
);

create table stations (
   name varchar(100),
   line varchar(50)
);
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT 
    fares_jan18.station AS name, 
    SUM(fares_feb1.ff - fares_jan18.ff) AS diff_feb1_jan18 
FROM
    fares_jan18 
    JOIN fares_feb1 ON fares_jan18.station = fares_feb1.station 
    JOIN stations   ON fares_jan18.station = stations.name 
WHERE
    stations.line ="Broadway" 
GROUP BY
    name 
ORDER BY
    name;
```

it does give me the correct table, but when ever there is more that one record, I get the duplicate the sum of the difference. For instance the result for a station with two values should be 33254, and it' giving me 66508. I have removed the group by from my query, it seems that I have for records instead of two.

I've read all I could on StackOverflow but I can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

Here is an image of my table:

[image]

Comment: You're using different tables in the query than you showed at the top.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary columns and changed table names to reflect the query. Hope my edit wasn't to substantial or deemed invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pre-aggregate each separately or you are getting a Cartesian result...  Since the query is for a single Broadway, a single record will result in each station when working the join from each date data source

```
SELECT
      justF18.name,
      justFeb1.SumFF - justF18.SumFF as FF_Diff
   from 
      ( SELECT f18.station AS name, 
               SUM(f18.ff) AS Sumff
           FROM 
              fares_jan18 f18
                 JOIN stations s ON f18.station = s.name 
                 AND s.line = "Broadway" 
           group by
              f18.station ) justF18
      JOIN
      ( SELECT feb1.station AS name, 
               SUM(feb1.ff) AS Sumff
           FROM 
              fares_feb1 feb1
                 JOIN stations s ON feb1.station = s.name 
                 AND s.line = "Broadway" 
           group by 
              feb1.station ) justFeb1
        ON justF18.name = justFeb1.name
   order by
      JustFeb18.name
```

Comment: Thank you,now I know that first I have to do the operations separately in each table.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a cartesian product of all the rows with the same stations in the two fares tables, and then summing the differences from each pair. You need to calculate the totals in each table separately in subqueries, and then subtract them.

```
SELECT s.name, feb1.total - jan18.total AS diff_feb1_jan18
FROM stations AS s
JOIN (SELECT station, SUM(ff) AS total
      FROM fares_feb1
      GROUP BY station) AS feb1
    ON feb1.station = s.station
JOIN (SELECT station, SUM(ff) AS total
      FROM fares_jan18
      GROUP BY station) AS jan18
    ON jan18.station = s.station
WHERE s.line = "Broadway"
ORDER BY s.name
```

Comment: I just changed the name of the column in s.station to s.name, since it's the name of the column in that table, and then it worked perfectly. I understood the logic and it would also apply to another problem. Thank you so much.